# Two markers on google map for one place

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have simple google map with markers.
When I create marker for example for Viet Nam I see two markers on Map (in the beginning and in the end, see screenshot).

Is there any way to show only one marker? I cannot change size or zoom of map.

Code:

```
function loadMap() {
 var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 1,
   disableDefaultUI: true,
   zoomControl: false,
   scrollwheel: false,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.0, -97.2070),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }
 MAP = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}

function addMarker(address) {
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: MAP,
    position: results[0].geometry.location
  });
  MARKERS.push(marker);
 }});
}
```

[image: Screenshot of two markers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved, I needed to add option "optimized: false" for markers. After this I have one marker for one place.[image: Map with one marker for a one place]

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: `No`, You basically see the same icon, in the same location. because you zoomed out the map that way that you see the same land twice. it's a normal behavior. there is no logic that in one round there will be a marker and in the second there wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the minimum zoom to a larger number so you won't be able to zoom out that far. But that comes with some issues, your map will have to have a fixed width.

Look at `minZoom` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

Otherwise I don't see how you can do that.